# AJAX Return Type from ASHX Handler

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, html, ajax

I'm writing a page that needs to exchange some information with a SQL server. For portability reasons, and because I hate writing ASP but I've been told to do this on the IIS 7 server, I'm writing the page in pure HTML, a generic handler (ASHX) in C# .NET to do the server-side stuff, and using AJAX to communicate between them. I've got this approach working using `Response.ContentType = "text/plain";`, but I'd like to return several pieces of information with one request, so I'm switching to XML or JSON, leaning toward XML.

So, to return XML, I change to `"text/xml"`, but then do I just `Response.Write` the whole XML code verbatim, or is there a more succinct way built into .NET? Same question for JSON. I know there are specific methods in jQuery (even just JavaScript) for parsing the returned data, so I was wondering if there was something similar in .NET to encode.

Comment: You should use ASP.Net MVC.  It's much nicer.

Comment: [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) would work well here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but then do I just Response.Write the whole XML code verbatim, or is
>   there a more succinct way built into .NET?

You could use a [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx), [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) or even a [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to build the XML and then write it to the `Response.OutputStream`.

Here's an example with a `XDocument`:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement(
            "messages",
            new XElement(
                "message", 
                new XAttribute("id", "1"), 
                new XAttribute("value", "message 1"), 
            ),
            new XElement(
                "message", 
                new XAttribute("id", "2"), 
                new XAttribute("value", "message 2")
            )
        )
    );
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(context.Response.OutputStream))
    {
        doc.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

> Same question for JSON

You would use a Json serializer such as [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and then write it to the output stream:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = serializer.Serialize(new
    {
        messages = new[]
        {
            new { id = 1, value = "message 1" },
            new { id = 2, value = "message 2" },
        }
    });
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.Write(json);
}
```

This being said, you should be aware that [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) or the knocking on the door [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) are now the preferred ways to expose such data instead of writing generic handlers.

Comment: Could you spare a brief example?

Comment: Note: using the JSON example you provided, I had to say `messages = new object[]`.

Comment: That's weird. Which version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: 3.5 on Frontpage. I'm about to move it to our not-deprecated server. Maybe that will help.